# siunitx – bar over repeating digits

Tags: siunitx

How to get a bar over repeating digits in `siunitx`? We would, for example, write `1/3 = 0.33\bar{3}` but the code `\num{0.33\bar{3}}` produces an "invalid number" error.

The `siunitx` manual does not mention the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
$ \num[parse-numbers=false]{654321.12\overline{34}}$
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
By option `[parse-numbers=false]` are lost may of siunitx`features in number formatting. So the same result you will get with`$ 654321.12\overline{34}$`. If you like to have grouping" in this number, you can insert it manually, as is done in the next MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
$ 654\,321.12\overline{34}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can use `\bar` if you like to have line over only one decimal digit:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
$ 654\,321.123\bar{4}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Something like that.

BUT with your proposal the user has to account for the correct decimal delimiter, which is not changed to your local setting and the code (in my oppinon) much to long for that little thing. In this case it would much shorter to wright (e. g. with the comma as delimiter) $\text{654321,12\bar{34}$ and append some units with \si{}.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great to have something like \num{65321,12\bar{34}}?

Comment: @Franklin, hm, it is not simple. You may consider send  to package author a features request ;-)

Comment: The user also must take care of the correct grouping of the digits.

Comment: I expanded, specified the question (see above) and added a MWE with its output.

Comment: New edit of MWE with according output based on the guidelines of DIN 1333.

Comment: @Franklin, if you have answers on your question, than please show it to us as an answer. If this is new question, please ask it as such. So far I don't know for better solution as is in my answer. You may wait on `siunitx` package author or some other guru for `siunitx` ar look around for solution without use of `siunitx` package. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: @ Zarko: All "answers" (my own ones included) are basicaly workarounds not real satisfying answers. I contacted the package author. He is thinking about that as a feature request for (one of) the next updates. Your answers only work for the dot as decimal delimiter, but there SI expects the comma. So I will post my different suggestions as answer for now, as there are no better ones within the current capbilites of siunits.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Zarko's suggestions, here is a MWE containing a table with different encodings. As you can see, if \num{} is placed inside a math environment AND the comma (,) shall be used as the decimal delimiter the comma behaves like a list separator, i. e. the first number after the comma moves away from the comma to the right. The correct behaviour can only be forced if the code is placed inside a \text{} statement. The last two lines shows the correct results without siunitx.

Note: Both, grouping or no-grouping of digits is allowed. If you choose grouping the overline over repeating digits must not be interrupted by the space between the groups [DIN 1333]. DIN 1333 (Zahlenangaben/Presentation of numerical data) is the only source I found adressing that topic. If anyone knows another international or  national standard clearing that point, please let me know.

```
  \documentclass{scrartcl}
    %--------------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{ngerman}
    \usepackage{booktabs}% just for the nice table
    %························································
    \usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
    \sisetup{mode=text}
    %--------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{document}
    %--------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{tabular} {lllll}
    \toprule
    No. & Output & Grpg. & Corr. & Delimiter\\
    \midrule
    a. & \num[parse-numbers=false]{654321.12\overline{345}} & no & yes & dot (.)\\
    b. & \num[parse-numbers=false]{654\,321.12\overline{3\,54}} & yes & yes & dot (.)\\
    \midrule
    c. & \num[parse-numbers=false]{654321,12\overline{\text{345}}} & no & no & comma (,)\\
    d. & \num[parse-numbers=false]{\text{654\,321,12}\overline{\text{345}}} & no & yes & comma (,)\\
    e. & $\num[parse-numbers=false]{654\,321,12\overline{\text{3\,45}}}$ & yes & no & comma (,)\\
    f. & $\num[parse-numbers=false]{\text{654\,321,12}\overline{\text{3\,45}}}$ & yes & yes & comma (,)\\
    \midrule
    g. & $\text{654321,12}\overline{\text{345}}$ & no & yes & comma (,)\\
    h. & $\text{654\,321,12}\overline{\text{3\,45}}$ & yes & yes & comma (,)\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    %--------------------------------------------------------
    \end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]