# siunitx – How to underline last digit or print in bold

Tags: siunitx

How to underline or print in bold the last digit in siunitx to express an exact decimal value? E. g. the speed of light c = 299 792 45**8** m/s. This way of handling exact decimal numbers is also specified by DIN 1333.

The siunitx manual does not say anything about that.

This question is related to question [siunitx – bar over repeating digits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646254/siunitx-bar-over-repeating-digits).

The solutions given there can easily be adapted here.

Comment: As we have discussed elsewhere, this would be a feature request, or at present would require internal 'fiddling'

Comment: I don't see the link to the other question: this one seems to be about significant digits, the other is about recurring digits (which _cannot_ occur in a physical measurement).

Comment: @ Joseph Wright: Yes. I was fully aware of our conversation. But I thought, other fellows might be interested as well and should be informed that there is "something going on".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MWE giving some solutions. See following picture

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%······························································
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%······························································
\begin{document}
%······························································
\begin{tabular}{l}
\toprule
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\text{299\,792\,45\textbf{8}}}{\meter\per\second}$\\
${\text{299\,792\,45\textbf{8}\,}}\si{\meter\per\second}$\\
\midrule
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\text{299\,792\,45\ul{8}}}{\meter\per\second}$\\
${\text{299\,792\,45\ul{8}\,}}\si{\meter\per\second}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%······························································
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]